# Trigger a Session Update when an object is updated elsewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a custom object that is referenced many times throughout a module in my system. Let me refer to it as CustomObj. To minimize the constant loading of this object from the DB I'd like to store it in Session in a collection of those objects. So I'd like to store a Dictionary of CustomObj where the key is the ID of the CustomObj. That way I can just check the Session if they key exists, then just reference that CustomObj over and over again, without the hit on the DB every time.

However, these CustomObjs can be updated by an Admin and their properties change. When that happens I'd like to broadcast down to the users connected to update that object in the dictionary to use the latest properties. Is there a built in process for doing this or would I need to implement some sort of broadcast and force an update via SignalR (I already have a hub setup for Facebook like notifications). Is Session the right place for this ?

The objects won't be updated extremely frequently or by alot of different Admins, but every once in a while the Admin will make a change to 1-5 properties, save, and the object is now different.

Comment: Side note: since in all real cases session state should be out-of-process you are very unlikely gain much performance improvements by using session state as cache. Make sure to actually measure if reading object every time it is needed is actually problem for your case - cache invalidation is not exactly the easiest thing to get right (https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/has-phil-karlton-ever-said-there-are-only-two-hard-things-in-computer-science )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal way to store an object in a session that is being modified by different users. In your case, Caching should be the recommended solution.